Why might mdfind queries with opposite logic find the same file?
This is on a Mac15,1 running Sequoia 15.1.1 (using OpenCores).
The difference between these two mdfind queries is the equal/not-equal in the second comparison but I'm confused by the results.
mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == "*SANCHEZ*" && kMDItemKind == *movie'
.../Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Movies/ANTONIO_SANCHEZ/ANTONIO_SANCHEZ.m4v

mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == "*SANCHEZ*" && kMDItemKind != *movie'
.../Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Movies/ANTONIO_SANCHEZ
.../Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Movies/ANTONIO_SANCHEZ/ANTONIO_SANCHEZ.m4v


The kMDItemKind key for the .m4v file is "Apple MPEG-4 movie" while it is "Folder" for the other result. It makes sense that the folder wouldn't be selected for the first query but I can't figure out why the .m4v file is still a result for the second query.
It gets stranger. If I change the search string for the "not-equal" query a bit, it correctly filters out the file (i.e. only the folder is a result):
mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == "*SANCHEZ*" && kMDItemKind != *mov*'                                                      
.../Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Movies/ANTONIO_SANCHEZ

But, if I add just one more character, it breaks again:
mdfind 'kMDItemFSName == "*SANCHEZ*" && kMDItemKind != *movi*'
.../Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Movies/ANTONIO_SANCHEZ
.../Music/iTunes/iTunes Music/Movies/ANTONIO_SANCHEZ/ANTONIO_SANCHEZ.m4v

The mdls output for the .m4v file is below. Note that I've rebooted and had the Spotlight database rebuilt.
mdls .../Music/iTunes/iTunes\ Music/Movies/ANTONIO_SANCHEZ/ANTONIO_SANCHEZ.m4v           
_kMDItemDisplayNameWithExtensions  = "ANTONIO_SANCHEZ.m4v"
com_apple_metadata_modtime         = 307728774
kMDItemContentCreationDate         = 2010-10-02 16:12:54 +0000
kMDItemContentCreationDate_Ranking = 2024-11-24 00:00:00 +0000
kMDItemContentModificationDate     = 2010-10-02 16:12:54 +0000
kMDItemContentType                 = "com.apple.m4v-video"
kMDItemContentTypeTree             = (
    "com.apple.m4v-video",
    "public.mpeg-4",
    "public.movie",
    "public.audiovisual-content",
    "public.data",
    "public.item",
    "public.content"
)
kMDItemDateAdded                   = 2024-11-24 22:10:35 +0000
kMDItemDisplayName                 = "ANTONIO_SANCHEZ.m4v"
kMDItemDocumentIdentifier          = 150904
kMDItemFSContentChangeDate         = 2010-10-02 16:12:54 +0000
kMDItemFSCreationDate              = 2010-10-02 16:12:54 +0000
kMDItemFSCreatorCode               = ""
kMDItemFSFinderFlags               = 0
kMDItemFSHasCustomIcon             = (null)
kMDItemFSInvisible                 = 0
kMDItemFSIsExtensionHidden         = 0
kMDItemFSIsStationery              = (null)
kMDItemFSLabel                     = 0
kMDItemFSName                      = "ANTONIO_SANCHEZ.m4v"
kMDItemFSNodeCount                 = (null)
kMDItemFSOwnerGroupID              = 20
kMDItemFSOwnerUserID               = 501
kMDItemFSSize                      = 2281678243
kMDItemFSTypeCode                  = ""
kMDItemInterestingDate_Ranking     = 2010-10-02 00:00:00 +0000
**kMDItemKind                        = "Apple MPEG-4 movie"**
kMDItemLogicalSize                 = 2281678243
kMDItemPhysicalSize                = 2281678243

It seems like whatever the kMDItemKind string is, the equal & not-equal comparisons shouldn't get the same results, right?
